# MVC get javascript files from another solution

Tags: javascript, cdn, asp.net-mvc-5

I have several solutions that acts like web parts.
I have one solution with several JavaScript files.
I want to load those JavaScript files from this solution in other solutions.
I have following options

- Create a class library and publish it on the company NuGet storage.
- Create a web application and load those JavaScript files with CDN.

  - This is not exactly a CDN, but is this the way how to make it ?
  - How to restrict access to this CDN to only those web parts ?

Is there another way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Take a look at this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398930.aspx Anyway I suggest you to use embedded resources. With an HttpHandler you can manage access to embedded files like js

Comment: Thanks for your input Roberto. But this is not the way I want to do it. When I deploy the application in the production environment, I have to copy the dll from somewhere to my bin folder. That's what we want to avoid.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand. What's your goal? What you want to do with production environment?

Comment: Roberto, I have a Web application and I deploy it in production. I have a class library with javascript files, that I also deploy to production but not on the same server. Now I have to use those javascript files from this library in my Web Application. 
I wanted to use a CDN, but my team members are not so happy with this solution, because we have to apply headers to restrict access only from certain web applications.
So I'm looking for another solution, what is the best way to accomplish this ?